# Error trying to run a PHP Hello World in Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, apache2

I installed the PDT PhP Development Tool in eclipse in order to run PhP files, but when I click in "Run as > PhP Web Aplication" it shows me a white page with the message:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /teste/teste.php was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.23 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 80

Apache is running normally in 127.0.0.1.

I have an info.php file at /var/www/info.php, I tryend to tun http://localhost/info.php but it gives the same Not Found error.

Yes, I'm newbie in PhP, I'm trying to run a simple Hello World Program.

```
<?php
    echo "Hello!";
?>
```

My info.php is:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I created a symlink for my project at /var/www/html, now it works!

Answer (score 1):

**Apache/Hosts**

When you tried to open http://localhost/info.php direct in your Browser (firefox etc.) and this won't work, the problem is in your apache/hosts configuration.

- Check in your apache.conf/httpd.conf the DocumentRoot
- Check your VirtualHost config (in httpd.conf or separate file)
- Check your /etc/hosts they should contain:

`127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost
 ::1             localhost.localdomain   localhost`

When the url works in your browser:

**Eclipse**
You have to create the Run Configurations:

1. Menu "Run" > "Run Configuration"
2. Select "PHP Web Application" and click the "New Button"
3. PHP Server: click on "New"
4. ServerName: just a name. Tipp: name it after your domain: "localhost"
5. Base URL: http://localhost
6. Document Root: path to your source folder
7. Finish (Back in Run Configuration)
8. File: your start file (index.php or in your case teste.php)
9. check if the url is correct, otherwise remove the check on "Auto Generate" and fix it
10. run > will open the url in the Built-In browser

To open the page in FireFox etc.: Menu "Preferences" > "General" > "Web Browser" > "Use external browser"